# How to get number of Facebook likes?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the number of Facebook likes on my Facebook page.
Currently, I am able to get it using this:

```
function fblikes() {
$pageID = $_GET['id'];
$pagelikes = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageID));
echo $pagelikes->likes;
}
```

Except, I would like it to display the short form of the number of likes instead of the entire number.

For example:
When I get the number of likes from http://graph.facebook.com/facebook, it displays as "91830595". I would like the number of likes to display as it does on http://www.facebook.com/facebook - "91m".

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well you have the number, just display it how you like. You know how to divide by 1,000,000 right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know from `Facebook` api we can do this, but you can do this in `PHP`

```
function nice_number($n) {
    // first strip any formatting;
    $n = (0+str_replace(",","",$n));

    // is this a number?
    if(!is_numeric($n)) return false;

    // now filter it;
    if($n>1000000000000) return round(($n/1000000000000),2).' trillion';
    else if($n>1000000000) return round(($n/1000000000),2).' billion';
    else if($n>1000000) return round(($n/1000000),2).' million';
    else if($n>1000) return round(($n/1000),2).' thousand';

    return number_format($n);
}

echo nice_number($pagelikes->likes);  // 91million
```

Answer (score 0):

The Yogesh answer is good, but the question has error.

For code to work you need to put

```
echo $pagelikes[ 'likes' ];
```

instead line

```
echo $pagelikes->likes;
```